# Application Specific Information: Application failed to launch in time (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, ios, launch

This is on the top of one of my crash reports. Is there any App Launch timeout limit determined by Apple? Any common workaround if so?

```
Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 13.700 (user 8.580, system 5.120), 67% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 6.180, 30% CPU
```

On an iPhone 3G.

I have to split/delay my launching tasks maybe...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it has to launch within 5 (or maybe 10) seconds or the iPhone assumes it has crashed.

Try to avoid loading a lot of stuff on your main thread at launch. If you need to load a lot of stuff do it on a background thread, like this:

```
- (void)startLoading
{
    //call this in your app delegate instead of setting window.rootViewController to your main view controller
    //you can show a UIActivityIndiocatorView here or something if you like

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadInBackground)];
}

- (void)loadInBackground
{
    //do your loading here
    //this is in the background, so don't try to access any UI elements

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishedLoading) withObject:nil waituntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)finishedLoading
{
    //back on the main thread now, it's safe to show your view controller
    window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: I actually made an "entrance" view controller showing Default.png with a UIActivityIndicator, then laod the rest of the views on the final callback.

Comment: Just a note for people who didn't notice in the code above.... you **MUST** interact with UIKit on the main thread, so if you're currently in a background thread then you need to `performSelectorOnMainThread:` as shown above.