# iOS app failed to launch in time 0x000000008badf00d - delay in applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, initialization, appdelegate

I put entire `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with minimal code which is here:

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
 m_bDataLoadingNeeded = YES;
 return YES;
```

As a result, I had to put crucial initialization in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.
Yet, I get the above error.

All references I get about it mentions to complete `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` sooner which I have done. Is there any check required for `applicationDidBecomeActive`?

My crash log is here (somehow, I can't symbolicate it with all dsym and app in place, so I can't know which statement is exact culprit. But everyone can see that it is definitely not `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`)

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
<MyBundleID> failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.600 (user 1.600, system 0.000), 4% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.438, 1% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c66f0fc 0x3c65e000 + 69884
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5b8124 0x3c5b7000 + 4388
2   SystemConfiguration             0x360d43ca 0x360c0000 + 82890
3   MyApp                           0x001cd406 0xf9000 + 869382
4   MyApp                           0x001ccb78 0xf9000 + 867192
5   MyApp                           0x001cd148 0xf9000 + 868680
6   MyApp                           0x001d77e4 0xf9000 + 911332
7   MyApp                           0x001d7ed0 0xf9000 + 913104
8   MyApp                           0x001cd908 0xf9000 + 870664
9   MyApp                           0x001d46e0 0xf9000 + 898784
10  MyApp                           0x000fb870 0xf9000 + 10352
11  UIKit                           0x36177af6 0x36102000 + 482038
12  UIKit                           0x3615d9bc 0x36102000 + 375228
13  UIKit                           0x36105c34 0x36102000 + 15412
14  UIKit                           0x361056c8 0x36102000 + 14024
15  UIKit                           0x36105116 0x36102000 + 12566
16  GraphicsServices                0x37dfb5a0 0x37df5000 + 26016
17  GraphicsServices                0x37dfb1ce 0x37df5000 + 25038
18  CoreFoundation                  0x342d2170 0x3423b000 + 618864
19  CoreFoundation                  0x342d2112 0x3423b000 + 618770
20  CoreFoundation                  0x342d0f94 0x3423b000 + 614292
21  CoreFoundation                  0x34243eb8 0x3423b000 + 36536
22  CoreFoundation                  0x34243d44 0x3423b000 + 36164
23  UIKit                           0x3615c480 0x36102000 + 369792
24  UIKit                           0x361592fc 0x36102000 + 357116
25  MyApp                           0x000fb4be 0xf9000 + 9406
26  MyApp                           0x000fb474 0xf9000 + 9332
```

**Considering `applicationDidBecomeActive` is indeed the culprit:**

I can move my `applicationDidBecomeActive` initialization inside background thread - something quite simplistic [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241008/application-specific-information-application-failed-to-launch-in-time-ios), but I am not sure what other things I will have to do, because this initialize code will in turn internally spawn more threads. I am using AFNetworking, Reachability and other frameworks which are block based. I don't know if I will end up so doing so many modifications to already built architecture and common code.

I am pretty confused how to tackle this in best and shortest possible way.

Comment: `0x8badf00d`... typical, why are you blocking the main thread during the launch? the job, which requires too long time to proceed, needs to be put into a background thread.

Comment: Use instruments to find the part of your code that is blocking the main thread and optimize that. Don't optimize things you don't know anything about, you might make it worse.

Comment: Well much of stuff is actually within background thread but not in a way that I can see, like AFNetworking calls etc. My confusion is how do I wrap that entire thing within one more background call? Also,I really don't see any word of caution for applicationDidBecomeActive - I also saw that it is actually called after my first viewdidLoad.

Comment: Its also important to understand that regardless of method if it takes too long the system will kill it. So if your applicationDidBecomeActive is taking 20 seconds, and you move that code somewhere else. iOS may just as likely kill it there as well. So you should look into backgrounding or splitting it up with UI updates in between.

Comment: I suggest that the best way is to solve your symbolication problem first so that you're not guessing about the rest of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect your program is making a bunch of network requests on the main thread before it is usable -- blocking the user out of interaction for seconds.

The backtrace is not (always/necessarily) important -- your app is being killed after a certain *time*.

You can probably just run this in Instruments and see where you are doing things which have the potential to take a long time; I/O, network requests -- move these off the main thread, and perform them **asynchronously**. Also evaluate the CPU hotspots. Initial launch times should be nowhere near that long.

Comment: +1 and thanks, I read up things lately that involves how to background stuff. My source of confusion was - there was no whistles against didBecomeActive, which was the source of crash in my case. I will lately try instruments to see things entirely where I could improve.