# Why does connecting back to an iOS background NSURLSession take too long waiting on a lock, crashing the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsurlsession

Why would connecting with an NSURLSession through its configuration take so long that it would crash the app on start up: 'failed to launch in time'?

I've seen similar crash dumps in many iOS apps including NY Times iOS app and Evernote app.

```
[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:queue]
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3afb7aa0 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3af04d3d _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 173
2   CFNetwork                       0x2febd8e3 -[__NSCFBackgroundSessionBridge setupBackgroundSession] + 379
3   CFNetwork                       0x2fef18a1 +[__NSCFSessionBridge bridgeForConfiguration:session:queue:] + 153
4   CFNetwork                       0x2fef6497 -[__NSCFURLSession initWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:] + 395
5   CFNetwork                       0x2fef6eb7 +[__NSCFURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:] + 295
```

Comment: I am also facing same problem with exact stack trace. Not able to find out root cause. @Rayyan, were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I moved the call to run asynchronously on a background thread so that the OS doesn't terminate the app due to this. However, the sessionWithConfiguration call then hangs and never returns. It rarely happens but once a device gets into bad state, it consistently hangs on that device. @kkumpavat, is this what you're seeing too? I suspect it's a bug in iOS.

Comment: Yes, I also suspect its a bug in iOS. Its happens rarely and once iOS gets into that bad state, execution hangs at 'sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:' every time. Also moving call to run asynchronously does not help as session never gets initialised and we wont be able to perform network task.

Comment: I seem to be getting this issue on iOS 8.3 as well. Did you ever work out a solution or workaround? I'm thinking I might just do this on a background queue, since I don't need it straight away at launch.

Comment: I also have this issue on iOS 8.3 (used to work OK on 8.2). Basically, if I have a large file background upload in progress and the app gets killed, it will always hang at restart, until I reboot the device. My current workaround is to store some flags in NSUserDefaults and reset them when receiving URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession notification. After that, it's safe to call sessionWithConfiguration. It's a risk thou that the notification will never be received and my flags will disable the service permanently.

Answer (score 1):

See [Application Specific Information: Application failed to launch in time (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241008/application-specific-information-application-failed-to-launch-in-time-ios) .

Basically there are 2 things to keep in mind:

1. Upon startup, you only have a few seconds to finish the startup procedure. Any longer running code should be called asynchronously after the app has started.
2. Make absolutely sure that any UI code in your callbacks/blocks/closures/etc... is called on the main thread. You must force it to do so.

Comment: @henry-asseily, thanks, this makes sense and I agree with your guidelines. What's unclear to me is why sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue: API takes a very long time, that it needs to be async so that it doesn't hold up the app on launch. The semantics of that API don't suggest that it can be a long running call, but perhaps I'm missing something.